# Git new branch then roll back to previous version

Tags: git

I have a few different branches including my master branch. I want to create a new branch from master which I think can be done like this correct me if I'm wrong.

```
git branch masterDup
git checkout masterDup
```

I then want to roll the masterDup branch back to an old version. Can this be done without effecting the master or any other branches. So only masterDup would be rolled back. 
If so how would I roll back using the commit ID just for this newly created branch.

I have the commit ID in the my log history. commit 6f041c1e37bb97aab35678d35c8923fabe33c8d2c

I'm using terminal for my git commands.

Comment: I'd recommend reading any [git book](http://git-scm.com/book) at least once, you obviously don't grasp even the git basics.

Comment: I wouldn't say that. Git in general is somewhat advanced computer knowledge. Most of the SO questions could be solved by rtfm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you check out a new branch with

```
git checkout -b masterDup
```

and then you reset it to an earlier version

```
git reset --hard HEAD~x
```

where x is x versions back (or use the hash if you like)

edited this answer, see comments.

Comment: `HEAD^x` refers to the xth parent in a merge commit! You mean `HEAD~x`. (Or `HEAD^^^^...` x times.)

Comment: What does the -b do in the checkout of the new branch

Comment: @vergenzt, yes you're right. I'm usually going back one commit so I frequently mix them up with no harm done.

Comment: @Chapsterj, you `checkout` a new `-b`ranch.

Comment: So in my case would it be git reset --hard HEAD~6f041c1e37bb97aab35678d35c8923fabe33c8d2c   or do I just leave out the ~ symbol and just have a space between the HEAD and the commit ID value.

Comment: @Chapsterj just revert via `git reset --hard 6f041c1e37bb97aab35678d35c8923fabe33c8d2c` This way your master branch is at HEAD and your masterDup at 6f041. Unless you merge them this is where they will stay.

Comment: This is why Git makes me happy.

Answer (score 0):

Right after the checkout of the new branch

```
git reset --hard 6f041c1e37bb97aab35678d35c8923fabe33c8d2c
```

Comment: Does git reset --hard 6f041c1e37bb97aab35678d35c8923fabe33c8d2c  effect any the other branches. Or only the branch I have checked  out.

Comment: Thanks Mario for the help also.